# Fullcalendar get current view on click of month time week etc

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Here whenever the events is trigger I want to know the current view of the calendar like if it is `dayGridMonth`, `timeGridWeek`, `timeGridDay` or `listWeek`.

I have an select element where on change I am trying to update events on calendar. But what is happening is, if I select list view and change select menu then the whole calendar is refresh to default view. I want to set the calendar to the same view it was before selecting select box.

```
    calendar_view_session: function(){
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction'],
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
        },

        defaultDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),//'2019-04-12',
        navLinks: true, 
        defaultView: 'listWeek',
        eventSources: [{
                    events: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
                        console.log(info);
                    },
                    ..........
            }
          ],
          ..........
  }
}



                <select name="select_meetingtype" id="select_meetingtype" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">All Sessions</option>
                    <option value="free_session">Free Sessions</option>
                    <option value="weekly_session">Classes</option>
                </select>

$('#select_meetingtype').on('change', function() {
  _this.calendar_view_session(this.value)
});
```

The `console.log(info)` is only printing dates.

[image]

Comment: `_this.calendar_view_session(this.value)` ...this is re-creating the whole calendar from scratch. So there's no surprise that it resets to the default view, because you've just destroyed the whole memory of the calendar and started a new one. There's no need to do that when all you want to do want to do is update the events. You should be running the [refetchEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents) function of the existing calendar object instead.

Comment: Please guide me how can I refetch events. I went through the docs link you gave but the function says `...not a function`. `calendarEl.refetchEvents()`

Comment: `calendarEl` is the HTML div element in your page, not your fullCalendar object. `calendar.refetchEvents()` is what you need to use. `calendar` is the calendar object you created by executing `new FullCalendar.Calendar`

Comment: Thanks it works. I also need to made calendar and calendarEl variable global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grab the current view, try this:

```
const views = {day: 'timeGridDay', week: 'timeGridWeek', month: 'timeGridMonth', list: 'listWeek'};
var currentView = 'listWeek';
$('#calendar_container').delegate('.fc-toolbar-chunk button', 'click', function(){
  currentView = views[$(this).text()];
  calendar_view_session();// re-initialize calendar with current selectedView
})

calendar_view_session: function(){
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        //
        //
        defaultView: currentView,// use global var instead of static value
        //
        //etc.
```

This will re-initialize your calendar with the current view instead of
reverting to the default one. The delegation is needed since the whole calendar gets destroyed and re-created when updating events.